# reboot command in GRUB2 bootloader

Tags: grub2, boot-loader, live-usb, reboot

I utilized `multibootusb` to create a bootable USB environment with multiple livecds. GRUB2 (GNU GRUB ver. 2.03) is the bootloader with some "minimal bash-like" shell that does not contain `reboot` or `halt` commands. Possible commands are:

```
all_functional_test
authenticate
background_color
background_image
badram
boot
break
chainloader
clear
configfile
continue
cpuid
cutmem
echo
export
extract_...
functional_test
gettext
initrd
insmod
linux
list_env
load_env
loadfont
loopback
ls
lsfonts
menuentry
net_...
normal
normal_exit
regexp
return
save_env
search_...
set
setparams
shift
source
submenu
syslinux_configfile
syslinux_source
terminal_output
terminal_input
test
unset
```

I am rather curious:

1. Is it possible to restart computer from that shell?
2. Is it possible to add new command that provides restart functionality?

Restart is done from GRUB with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> keys.

Comment: I'm not sure where you got this list from, but the docs say there are both `halt` and `reboot` commands: https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Command_002dline-and-menu-entry-commands.html

Comment: I got it from my computer in real action ([img](https://ibb.co/MNwjTB7)),  although `qemu` emulator shows full set of commands. I don't know why my computer does not load `GRUB` fully.